# Laravel Schedule not triggering job

Tags: laravel, cron

I do have a docker file runing a laravel app and some runners.

The schedule is triggering the command but it is not doing anything.
Whenever I try to run the command manually it works fine.

The command consulta_a1 dispatch a job that is suposed to fail, doing so the supervisor will log it on super.txt.

When the schedule run the command nothing happens, whenever I run the comand on the console it works as expected.

I configured my kernel in the following way:

```
protected $commands = [
    Commands\ConsultaDfeA1Command::class
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
    if (env("AMBIENTE") == "2") {
        $schedule->command('consultar_a1')->dailyAt('12:23');
        $schedule->command('consultar_a1')->dailyAt('12:28');
    }
    if (env("AMBIENTE") == "1") {
        $schedule->command('consultar_a1')->cron('0 0,3,6,9,12,18,21 * * *');
    }
}

/**
 * Register the commands for the application.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function commands()
{
    $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

    require base_path('routes/console.php');
}
```

In this screenshot we can se that the scheduler is configured and that I ran the exact command that the schedule is suposed to work.

[image]

The cron triggered the schedule.

[image]

But whenever I  check my supervisor jobs log just the manual actions were triggered.

[image]

Crontab -l:

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php  /var/www/artisan schedule:run 1>> /var/log/cron-log 2>&1
```

I have no idea what is happening and if any other infos are missing.

Comment: No images on SO!

Comment: @Roadowl sry Didn't understand what u mean.

Comment: The cron configuration should be `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` no specefic time (handled by laravel schedule) no specific commands (handled by laravel schedule)

Comment: @N69S Thats my cron... except that i'm saving the log for debug. As you can se in the image the cron is triggering, but the command that laravel is suposed to execute isn't.